# React Native app stuck at "Loading dependency graph done" in Simulators

Tags: react-native

While running react native app in simulators, the metro bundler stuck at "Loading dependency graph done".It works fine in real devices. What will be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried running the emulator in advance?

Answer (score 0):

it is not stuck, it finished.

you might get the message:

Running Metro Bundler on port **8081**.

Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to
  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native

if so, then you can open http://127.0.0.1:**8081**

note the port since it might change.
open the url in your browser and you will see it was not stuck.

to make it easier, use Expo XDE to create the app, and to start it.
follow the steps on this page: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started